# I have a question about the state value in React (plz help me.......)

Tags: reactjs

```
//todos.js
const ADD_TODO='todos/ADD_TODO';
const TOGGLE_TODO='todos/TOGGLE_TODO';

let nextId=1;
export const addTodo=(title,text)=>({
    type:ADD_TODO,
    todo:{
        id:nextId++,
        title,
        text
    }
});
export const toggleTodo=id=>({
    type:TOGGLE_TODO,
    id
});

const initialState={
    current_memo:0,
    memolist:[
        {
            id:1,
            title:'i am',
            text:'so tired'
        },
    ]
};

export default function todos(state=initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case ADD_TODO:
            return{
                ...state,
                state: state.memolist.concat(action.todo), //Question 1.
                current_memo: action.todo.id
            } 
        
        case TOGGLE_TODO:
            return state.current_memo;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}


//TodosContainer.js
function TodosContainer(){
    const todos=useSelector(state=>state.todos);  //Question 3.
    const dispatch=useDispatch();
    
    const onCreate=useCallback((title,text)=>dispatch(addTodo(title,text)),[dispatch]);
    const onToggle=useCallback(id =>dispatch(toggleTodo(id)),[dispatch]);

    return <Todos
        todos={todos}
        onCreate={onCreate}
        onToggle={onToggle}
    />;
}

export default TodosContainer;
```

Question 1.
What exactly does state mean in this case? Is initialState all? I want to add an array to the memolist through ADD_MEMO type, but it does not run normally. What is the problem?

Question 2.

```
current_memo:0,
    memolist:[
        {
            id:1,
            title:'i am',
            text:'is tired'
        },
        {
            id:2,
            title:'who am i',
            text:'where is it'
        },
    ]
```

If the array is like this, and you want to get the title by accessing the first array of memolist. state.memolist[1].title Can I access it like this? I don't know the approach.

Question 3.
Which of the entire initialState values ​​is the todos received by useSelector? How do I get a memolist?

I would be really grateful if you could tell me one thing...

Comment: The state I was talking about in the first question means the state in the function'todos'

Answer (score 2):

> What exactly does state mean in this case? Is initialState all? I want to add an array to the memolist through ADD_MEMO type, but it does not run normally. What is the problem?

- For every Reducer, it needs an initial state. Through action such as ADD_MEMO, you can update the state such as memolist. Go through the [link](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers) to understand the redux flow better.
- If you want to update the array, you have to do it in immutable way. It wont work as the concat() wont work. `state: state.memolist.concat(action.todo)`.

```
case ADD_TODO:
            return{
                ...state,
                memolist: [ ... state.memolist , 
                            {
                              id: action.todo.id,
                              text: action.todo.text,
                              completed: true
                            }
                          ]
                current_memo: action.todo.id
            }
```

> If the array is like this, and you want to get the title by accessing the first array of memolist. state.memolist[1](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers).title Can I access it like this? I don't know the approach.
> [Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp) starts the index from 0. So it will be `memolist[0].title`

> Which of the entire initialState values ​​is the todos received by useSelector? How do I get a memolist?

- useSelector accepts a single function, which we call a selector function. A selector is a function that takes the entire Redux store state as its argument, reads some value from the state, and returns that result.
- Try printing the state values after running the below line. it's like from the all the things, you will pick your thing.

`const todos=useSelector(state=>state.memolist);`

Answer (score 1):

Your example isn't just using React on its own. It's also using Redux to maintain and mutate the application's global state.

The method todos() takes in a state (with a default value of initialState) and an action and returns a mutated state based on that action.

For example, if if the action were of type ADD_TODO, it would return the state with an additional item added to it.

The TodosContainer is pulling its values from the Redux store with the "useSelector".